# Can vimtex be integrated with a DVI viewer?

Tags: vim, dvi

Is it possible to configure vimtex to produce a DVI file (instead of PDF) from the a latex source file and update an external DVI viewer? This could potentially speed up the compilation times.

Comment: The first question (can it make DVI output) is pretty easy: yes. Look for `g:vimtex_compiler` in the [documentation](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt). The second question (can it fire a viewer to view DVI files) is harder. vimtex's configuration for viewers implicitly assume that you want to view a PDF file. I am not sure if it will pick up on the DVI output.

Comment: That said, I think this question is much better asked on the [vimtex issue tracker](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues) than here, since I suspect this will involve some amount of vim hackery that is not really the focus of this site.